# Include views in a Rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm building a Rails plugin that currently provides controllers and models to an app. However I get a missing template error when it comes to views. I have the following:

```
%w{ models controllers views }.each do |dir|
  path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'app', dir)
  $LOAD_PATH << path
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << path
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_once_paths.delete(path)
end
```

The controllers and models are loaded but not views. The [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/plugins.html) says it can be done but doesn't have an example. Is there a way to include them (or a similar alternative)?

Comment: What's gem that you used

Comment: TBH the plugin approach has been phased out in favor of [engines](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html). It also might make this process easier.

Comment: It seems it's already been asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446402/rails-render-a-partial-from-a-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include the version you're working with ... reason that's important is after rails 4 came out - you're not supposed to be doing plugins anymore ... [Gem Vs Plugin Vs Engine in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118472/gem-vs-plugin-vs-engine-in-ruby-on-rails).

If you're not supporting a legacy app, would highly recommend going with a 'rails engine', the [Devise Gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is one great example...it's a self-encapsulated app, with it's own view files & sounds exactly like what you're trying to do.  Additionally, it shows you can even use generators to move your default views/controllers out of the engine & change the basic routing if someone needs to customize your work further.